# How to Hide Text Link Generated By Link_To

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a log in with facebook button

```
<p><%= link_to "Sign in with facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :class=>"btn fbSignin", :role => "button", :title => "Sign-in with Facebook"%></p>
```

so far this gets generated

```
<a class="btn fbSignin" href="/users/auth/facebook" role="button" title="Sign-in with Facebook">Sign in with facebook</a>
```

I am mounting a design onto a rails app.

The problem is a link that says "Sign in with facebook" gets generated but a box already got generated and it also says sign in with facebook. I tried using `button_to` instead but the result is the same.

If i do this instead

```
<p><%= link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :class=>"btn fbSignin", :role => "button", :title => "Sign-in with Facebook"%></p>
```

then `/users/auth/facebook` gets outputted. I want to hide the outputted link but make the box work properly (going to the right path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about use your text as first arg of the link_to? It outputs the path because you haven't specify the link body(as first argument) [#see_here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

Try this:

```
<p><%= link_to '', user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :class=>"btn fbSignin", :role => "button", :title => "Sign-in with Facebook"%></p>
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can have it like this

```
<%= link_to some_path do %>
  <strong>Awesome link</strong> -- it's pretty awesome
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "", some_path  %>
```

or simply use anchor tag

```
<a class="btn fbSignin" href="<%= user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>" role="button" title="Sign-in with Facebook"></a>
```